# Exception trying to Start a process after copying the file

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an annoying error like:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AceHc\trfpt.exe' because it is being used by another process.

The error happens when I try to use Process.Start after File.Copy the same file.

Code:

```
File.Copy(PathFrom & "\trfpt.exe", PathTo & "\trfpt.exe", True)
Process.Start(PathTo & "\trfpt.exe")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a virus scanner that might be scanning the file directly after the copy and blocking it?

It might be worth trying to temporarily disable it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Everything is fine with Anti-Virus and the file is fully copied than I start trying to open the .EXE but it throws the exception.

Comment: I've done all you sugested but I've the same error.. I'ts not about anti-virus, maybe a VS 2010 bug? :/

Answer (score 0):

Also, depending in the size of the file, maybe the EXE file is still being copied (that is, the copy function doesn't block que program flow, your code continue and the copy process continue in background).

Answer (score 0):

Download [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) from Windows Sysinternals and run it as admin from cmd to get a list of processes which hold a handle on that file:

> handle.exe trfpt.exe

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess - do you have a Windows Explorer window open looking at the folder 'Pathto' ?